# How to rotate the imageView in a UIButton, and NOT scale it

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton, core-graphics

I am endeavouring to rotate the imageView property of a UIBUtton without scaling it. The image in question is 24x18 - wider than it is tall - but once rotated into place the image is being scaled to keep those dimension  - leaving me with a very squished image. How can I prevent this?

Below is my code ..

```
-(IBAction)rotateButton
{
NSLog( @"Rotating button" );

[UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5f];
if( CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform( button.imageView.transform, CGAffineTransformIdentity ) )
{
    button.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
} else {
    button.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This **doesn't** happen if I apply the transform to the button instead of button.imageView, so I'm guessing it's a property of imageView that I'm not setting right.

Your clues & boos are most welcome

M.

Comment: FWIW, I get the squished result even when the transform is applied to the button. And it doesn't happen on simulator, only on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the UIImageView property of UIButtons behave very strangely--it seems that some of their properties are read-only, including the UIViewContentMode setting that is what you're talking about here.

The best solution I've found is to mimic the "button containing an image" setup with a separate UIImageView, and an empty custom-styled UIButton sitting on top of it. Gives you a lot more flexibility to manage the image.

Comment: I had a similar problem with ordinary UIImageViews and the content going insane when you rotate (NOT what should happen) that was fixed by setting contentMode to "Center" - thanks for this insight!

Answer (score 62):

Apply following code on initialization of view somewhere in view did load. This will help. The answer that you got above is not a true answer :)

```
button.imageView.clipsToBounds = NO;
button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Comment: Worth note you cannot set (or rely) on `button.imageEdgeInsets` as due to `clipsToBounds = NO` it doesn't have an effect.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that subclassing `UIButton` to remove the transform during `layoutSubviews` worked, like this:

```
class RotatableImageButton: UIButton {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        let originalTransform = imageView?.transform
        imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if let originalTransform = originalTransform {
            imageView?.transform = originalTransform
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed an issue for me where the rounded system icon "gear" was becoming an oval when rotating 90° via `self.btnSettings.imageView!.transform = self.btnSettings.imageView!.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(.pi / 2.0))` and only displayed correctly as a circle for 0° and 180°. After using your class, the gear icon maintained its shape correctly for 90° increments in rotation. Thanks.